# Display more than one webpage inside a JFrame

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, jeditorpane

How can I display more than one webpage inside a `JFrame`?

```
    JEditorPane website = new JEditorPane(line);
    website.setEditable(false);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JxBrowser");
    addressBar.setText(line);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(website));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

I have put this code inside a `for` loop, as usual  website  are open in different frame, I want all my browser websites to be open inside a single frame,

How this is possible?

Comment: Real browsers typically use tabs, right? And Swing has a JTabbedPane.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) Note that among the many suggestions for alternatives is (probably the most logical one) as suggested by @JBNizet.

Answer (score 0):

As @JBNizet mentioned in the comments, you could use a JTabbedPane.

Instead of adding the website JEditorPane directly to the JFrame, do this:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.add("Website Title", new JScrollPane(website));
frame.add(tabbedPane);
```

Of course, you shouldn't create a new JTabbedPane or new JFrame for each website, instead you should just add the website as a new tab to the already existing tabbed pane.

Don't forget that each tab would require their own addressBar object.